# Deslizar imagenes estilo instagram

Tags: android, kotlin, jetpack-compose, instagram

estoy armando una app para android, usando kotlin y jetpack compose. Quiero armar un carrucel de imagenes que funcione parecido a el que usa instagram ( un post que tiene imagenes que se deslizan horizontalmente ).
Logre hacerlo con LazyRow pero la realidad no me gusta mucho como queda, hay alguna alternativa o ejemplo que este en la red ( yo no lo encuentro ) para realizar esto.

Muchas gracias.